# Laravel Eloquent how to get the second or third record?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an Order and a Product models.
`"Order"` HasMany Product (and Product belongsTo Order)...

Let's say I want to display the 3 products of my order, how to do that ?
I know the first could be retrieved like `$order->products->first()`... but how to retrieve the second and third product?

I tried `$order->products->find(1)` but "1" represents the id of the product... which I don't want to know...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I finally found the solution, this is the correct syntax:

```
 $order->products->get(0)->name;   will return the first record
 $order->products->get(1)->name;   will return the second record
 $order->products->get(2)->name;   will return the third record
```

And so on...

Answer (score 75):

```
$order->products()->skip(1)->first();//Second row
$order->products()->skip(2)->first();//Third row
....
```

Is more performant than loading all products and getting only first, second, ecc..

---

Instead **if you want both second and third**, you can get only them in a single query without load other rows, with similar approach:

```
$order->products()->skip(1)->take(2)->get(); //Skip first, take second and third
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$order->products()->skip(1)->take(1)->first(); //Second row
$order->products()->skip(2)->take(1)->first(); //Third row

$order->products()->orderBy('salary','desc')->skip(1)->take(1)->first(); //Second highest salary row
$order->products()->orderBy('salary','desc')->skip(2)->take(1)->first(); //Third highest salary row
```

Answer (score 2):

Say you want a second product from `Eloquent Collection`

if you are sure that the array keys are same as array indexes, do that

```
$order->products->get(1)->name;
```

if you need the second item and you are not sure about the array keys, do this

```
$order->products->slice(1, 1)->first()->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try this :

```
$order->products->take(3)->get();
```

Comment: For example, if I need the product name, I tried $order->products->take(3)->get('name'); (I get a null result),   then I tried  $order->products->take(3)->get()->name;  (I get an error "missing argument")

Comment: Try this `$order->products->take(3)->select('name')->get()`

Comment: Still does not work: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::select()"

Comment: maybe try $order->products()->take(3)->get();